# RabbitMQ crashing on boot

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ has recently started crashing for me. I suspect I updated something by accident. On MacOS 10.15.7, `brew list rabbitmq` finds various files in `/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.8.14`.

When I try to run `rabbitmq-server` or any `rabbitmqctl` command, such as `rabbitmqctl version`, it crashes with:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{load_failed,[supervisor,logger_backend,logger_simple_h,logger_config,gen_event,logger_server,kernel,file_io_server,file_server,filename,file,erl_parse,erl_lint,application_controller,error_logger,lists,application,application_master,code,error_handler,logger,logger_filters,heart,gen_server,gen,ets,proc_lib,erl_eval,code_server]}}
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling has not helped.

The error is similar to the one [described here](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/O6nTPME65FA), where this was suggested:

> Some modules cannot be loaded. You very likely run a version of Erlang that's older than the oldest one supported by RabbitMQ

But according to [the docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html), RabbitMQ `3.8.14` requires Erlang `22.3` to `23.x`, and `erl --version` prints `Erlang/OTP 23`.

See [the `erl_crash.dump`](https://gist.github.com/nathanl/ae93369da2c1d3e2b05588dcfd725fee).

Any clues about what's wrong?

Comment: Is there a way to attach the crash dump file here on SO?

Comment: Hmm. Usually, I'd consider this eligible for migration to [unix.se] or somewhere more focused on system administration as opposed to software development.

Comment: ...one thing I would suggest, to be able to comply with [mre] guidelines, would be to try Dockerizing your RabbitMQ service; once you have a Dockerfile that runs it, that gives you something that can be distributed to others to let them reproduce the details of the environment (mostly; Docker isn't as good at that as Nix is, but asking folks to work with Nix is a heavy lift) and test proposed fixes. Docker for Mac _is_ very much a thing.

Comment: I appreciate the idea of a minimal reproducible example, and I use them often when filing bug reports with libraries. But in this case I don't know what all the pieces even are, much less what combination of pieces create this problem.

Comment: _nod_. The tricky thing for folks who might otherwise be answering is that we're placed in much the same position (at least, without digging into the crash dump). If you try to build a Dockerized reproducer and fail... well, then you find yourself with a working, Dockerized version of RabbitMQ; deploy it in place of the system-level instance and there you are. :) And if you try to build it and succeed, then  you can hand it to other folks who are then able to see the problem themselves and test their answers.

Comment: ...but our position is even worse: You can inspect the actual system where the problem occurs; we can't.

Comment: Yep, I understand. I'm basically hoping that someone goes "I've seen that, I know what causes it", the question gets answered, and in the future, web searches for the error message find this answer.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue on a Mac M1. I had erlang installed via asdf.

Rabbitmq was working without any problems, but after a brew update, something happened and we started getting the same error.

what worked for me was:

Uninstalling rabbitmq and brew's erlang

```
brew uninstall rabbitmq
brew uninstall erlang
```

Reinstalling them:

```
brew install rabbitmq
```

and finally, the most important thing was to bypass erlang commands to the system version (brew).:

```
asdf global erlang system
```

After doing this restarting rabbitmq made everything go back to normal.:

```
brew services restart rabbitmq
```

Comment: Maybe this goes without saying, but after doing `asdf global erlang system`, if you run a command like `rabbitmq-server` in a path that has a `.tool-versions` file, whatever it specifies will override the global version.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling RabbitMQ and all Erlang versions, then doing `brew install rabbitmq`, finally fixed this.

I got [this answer in the Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/PaQ528RSt8A/m/teOWPneSAwAJ):

> Something is off about the Erlang installation. A number of standard library modules cannot be loaded (but the version is indeed 23 according to the crash dump file).
> Consider uninstalling RabbitMQ *and* all Erlang versions (Homebrew-installed RabbitMQ also may pick up a version that's not Homebrew-provided, in theory).
> Since Homebrew uses a binary build that you can easily run with any Erlang in PATH, you can try without Homebrew [1].
> `kerl` [2] is a trivial way to build any Erlang release on macOS in case you need to do it, e.g. for comparison.
>
> 1. https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-generic-unix.html
> 2. https://github.com/kerl/kerl